# HttpWebRequest is not visible in my System.Net Reference

Tags: c#

I have a WindowsApplication project where the Reference-folder is missing a file. I've compared it with another project where I do find the file, and it should be found here:
References->System->System.Net->HttpWebRequest

How can I add this file to my project, and why isn't it loaded automatically, have I done something wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GetStockData
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string ticker = this.tbTicker.Text;
            DateTime startDate = this.dtpStart.Value;
            DateTime endDate = this.dtpEnd.Value;

            int startMonth = startDate.Month - 1;
            int endMonth = endDate.Month - 1;
            string theURL = @"http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" 
                + ticker + @"&a=" + startMonth.ToString() + @"&b=" + startDate.Day.ToString() 
                + @"&c=" + startDate.Year.ToString() + @"&d=" + endMonth.ToString() + @"&e=" + endDate.Day.ToString() 
                + @"&f=" + endDate.Year.ToString() + @"&g=d&ignore=.csv";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(theURL);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            string tempString = null;
            int count = 0;

            do {
                count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                if (count != 0) {
                    tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
                    sb.Append(tempString);
                    }
            }
            while (count > 0);
            string data = sb.ToString();
            String[] data2 = data.Split('\n');
            int iteration = 0;
            dates = new DateTime[data2.Length - 2];
            open = new double[data2.Length - 2];
            high = new double[data2.Length - 2];
            low = new double[data2.Length - 2];
            close = new double[data2.Length - 2];
            volume = new double[data2.Length - 2];
            adjClose = new double[data2.Length - 2];
            foreach (string strLine in data2)
            {
                String[] entries = strLine.Split(',');
                if ((iteration != 0) && (entries[0] != ""))
                {
                    dates[iteration - 1] = System.Convert.ToDateTime(entries[0]);
                    open[iteration - 1] = System.Convert.ToDouble(entries[1]);
                    high[iteration - 1] = System.Convert.ToDouble(entries[2]);
                    low[iteration - 1] = System.Convert.ToDouble(entries[3]);
                    close[iteration - 1] = System.Convert.ToDouble(entries[4]);
                    volume[iteration - 1] = System.Convert.ToDouble(entries[5]);
                    adjClose[iteration - 1] = System.Convert.ToDouble(entries[6]);
                }
                iteration = iteration + 1;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Kind regards
Espen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> have I done something wrong?

You forgot to add:

```
using System.Net;
```

in order to bring the namespace in which the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class is defined into scope.

Comment: Thanks Darin! It was not written in the code that I copied from, and I'm too inexperienced too catch the missing statement.

I notice that Stream and .GetResponseStream

dates, open, high etc etc are all colored black, in other words they seems not to be working properly. Is there any obvious stuff I've forgot to add?

Comment: `using System.IO;` add this

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace GetStockData
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string ticker = this.tbTicker.Text;
            DateTime startDate = this.dtpStart.Value;
            DateTime endDate = this.dtpEnd.Value;

            int startMonth = startDate.Month - 1;
            int endMonth = endDate.Month - 1;
            string theURL = @"http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" 
            + ticker + @"&a=" + startMonth.ToString() + @"&b=" + startDate.Day.ToString() 
            + @"&c=" + startDate.Year.ToString() + @"&d=" + endMonth.ToString() + @"&e=" + endDate.Day.ToString() 
            + @"&f=" + endDate.Year.ToString() + @"&g=d&ignore=.csv";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(theURL);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            string tempString = null;
            int count = 0;

            do {
                count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                if (count != 0) {
                    tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
                    sb.Append(tempString);
                }
            }
            while (count > 0);
            string data = sb.ToString();
            String[] data2 = data.Split('\n');
            int iteration = 0;
            dates = new DateTime[data2.Length - 2];
            open = new double[data2.Length - 2];
            high = new double[data2.Length - 2];
            low = new double[data2.Length - 2];
            close = new double[data2.Length - 2];
            volume = new double[data2.Length - 2];
            adjClose = new double[data2.Length - 2];
            foreach (string strLine in data2)
            {
                String[] entries = strLine.Split(',');
```